# Delphi application - Block windows-key (Start) on Windows 8

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-8, screen

I' programming a Delphi application. My goal is to cover ALL screen with my application to force user to fill my form. Application will be run as scheduled task.

My problem is, that normally, Windows does not allow applications to block other users action.

In Windows 7 I can run my application as scr file (screen saver), with no title bar and set `StayOnTop`. In this case, other application even if visible on "Window key" (start), stays behind my application, so my goal is reached.
Unfortunately, in Windows 8 this solution does not work because "window key" shows start screen, when I can run anything and this "anything" stays on top.

I tried some trick with code below, but without success.

```
  h := FindWindowEx(FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil),0,'Button',nil);
  ShowWindow(h,0); 
  Windows.SetParent(h,0);
```

How to block 'window key' (start button) action in the entire Windows 8 system?

Comment: You can look at replacing the explorer.exe shell with your Application. This works very well to create a completely stand-alone App. I've done this by reprogramming my app to execute explorer.exe if it is shut down.

Comment: Yes, I know... I have also used this solution once, when the only allowed application on some workstation was my one. I can not use it in this case, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't test it on windows 8, but in principle one can use a keyboard hook to discard the key-press.

Something similar to the following:

```
const   
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL   =   13;
    LLKHF_ALTDOWN    =   $00000020;
    LLKHF_INJECTED   =   $00000010;

type
    tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   record
        vkCode:   DWORD;
        scanCode:   DWORD;
        flags:   DWORD;
        time:   DWORD;
        dwExtraInfo:   DWORD;
      end;
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
    LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   ^KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT   =   ^KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;

var
    hhkLowLevelKybd:   HHOOK;

function LowLevelKeyBoardProc(nCode:   Integer;   awParam:   WPARAM;   alParam:   LPARAM):   LRESULT;   stdcall;
var
    fEatKeyStroke:   Boolean;
    p:   PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
begin
    fEatKeystroke   :=   False;
    if active and(  nCode   =   HC_ACTION)   then
    begin
        case   awParam   of
            WM_KEYDOWN,
            WM_SYSKEYDOWN,
            WM_KEYUP,
            WM_SYSKEYUP:
                begin
                    p   :=   PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(alParam);
                    if DisableWinKeys then
                     begin
                      if p^.vkCode   =   VK_LWIN
                        then fEatKeystroke   :=   True;
                      if p^.vkCode   =   VK_RWIN
                        then fEatKeystroke   :=   True;
                     end;
                end;
        end;
    end;
    if   fEatKeyStroke   then
        Result := 1
    else
        Result := CallNextHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd, nCode, awParam, alParam);
end;

procedure InstallHook;
begin
  if hhkLowLevelKybd <> 0 then exit;
  hhkLowLevelKybd := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @LowLevelKeyboardProc,   hInstance,   0);
end;

procedure UninstallHook;
begin
  if hhkLowLevelKybd = 0 then exit;
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd);
  hhkLowLevelKybd := 0;
end;
```

Comment: @CodeInChaos... You are the man! Your code works without changes even in windows 8. I would vote your solution up, but I have not sufficient reputation :(

Comment: Very good - the code still works with Windows 10 after some little corrections (deleting "active" and the line "if DisableWinKeys then". Good Job!